# Como puedo sumar dos digitos entre si

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones, variables, bucles

quisiera ayuda con lo siguiente:

Tengo un array con datos de tipo numero y string Ejm: ['8', 14, '6', 10, '4', 6, '2', 2];

quisiera realizar un ciclo que me permita tomar el valor mayor o igual a 10 y sumarlo entre si; ejm 14 => 1+4 =5...

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
const validator = {
    isValid: function (creditCardNumber){
        const numberPosition = creditCardNumber.split("").reverse(); 
        let sum = 0; 

        for(let i=0; i<numberPosition.length; i++){

            
            if(i%2 !=0){
                
                numberPosition[i] = numberPosition[i] * 2;

            }
            console.log(numberPosition);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu duda es como sumar los dígitos de un número o hay algo más?

Comment: si sumar los dos digitos entre si y luego ese resuktado sumarlo al resto de valores que estan dentro del array q puse como ejemplo. Si me puedes ayudar te lo agradezco muchisimo, estoy bloqueada

Comment: @NAIMERITHDANIELAMAGDALENO ¿Sumar entre si el primer digito que sea 10 o > y luego sumar los valores del array más el valor que se encontró ? ¿así no? o sea, el mayor de su array ejemplo seria 10 y el total seria: 53..... 1+0 = 1 luego  1+8+14+6+4+6+2+2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando los comentarios que realizaste en el comentario de tu pregunta.

> sumar los dos digitos entre si y luego ese resuktado sumarlo al resto de valores que estan dentro del array q puse como ejemplo.

Podría ser lo siguiente:

```js
const funcionSumatoria = (elementos) => {
  var aux = 0;
  var maxNumber = 0;
  var resultado = 0;

  elementos.forEach((element) => {
    if (element >= 10) {
      if (element >= aux) {
        maxNumber = element;
      }
      aux = element;
    }
  });
  if (!maxNumber) {
    return "No existe un número mayor a 10";
  }

  //Sumatoria de todo los elementos.
  aux = elementos.reduce((acc, value) => acc + parseInt(value), 0);

  //Separación de elementos considerando el máximo.
  maxNumber = maxNumber.toString().split("");
  maxNumber = maxNumber.reduce((acc, val) => acc + parseInt(val), 0);
  console.log("Suma de los digitos del número mayor: ", maxNumber);

  resultado = aux + maxNumber;
  console.log(
    "Suma de todo los elementos del array más la sumatoria de los digitos del número mayor: ",
    resultado
  );

  return resultado;
};

funcionSumatoria(["8", 14, "6", 10, "4", 6, "2", 2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

creo que lo buscas es sumar números mayores o iguales a 10 de un arreglo.
Puedes usar una función simple como esta.

```js
    function acum(n){
        var txt = '',
        split = [],
        res = 0,
        out = [], 
        num = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<n.length;i++){
            txt = n[i].toString(),
            num = parseInt(n[i]),
            res = 0;
            if(num >= 10){
                split = txt.split('');
                for(var j=0;j<split.length;j++){
                    res = res+parseInt(split[j]);
                }
                txt = res.toString();
            }
            out[i] = txt;
        }
        return out;
    }
    
var array = ['8', 14, '6', 10, '4', 6, '2', 2],
response = acum(array);
console.log(response);
```

Comment: Gracias ElJavinci voy a probarlo!!